# Extrayendo componentes en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en React js y me surgen un par de dudas que me gustaría aclarar antes de seguir desarrollando.

Según tengo entendido la unica diferencia entre

```
function User(props) {
    return (<li>props.userName</li>);
}
```

Y

```
User: function(props) {
    return (<li>props.userName</li>);
}
```

Es que la primera es notación ES6 y la segunda ES5. Ahora, si yo quiero llamar a este componente, me gustaría saber si hay alguna diferencia entre hacerlo así:

```
function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className="prueba">
        <User user={props.user} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

O así:

```
function Comment(props) {
  return (
    <div className="prueba">
        {User(props.userr)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 introduce clases y herencia al lenguaje mientras que en ES5 no los posee, esta hace la diferencia entre la definición de un componente React en ES5 y ES6, aunque en ambos casos estas haciendo lo mismo semánticamente (definir un componente), técnicamente React hace dos cosas muy distintas, en ES5 estas usando una función de React .createComponent que recibe un objeto donde tu provees la implementación de los metodos base junto a tus propios metodos del nuevo componente React, este método .createCompnent se encarga de fabricar el componente por ti mientras que en ES6 si estas utilizando clases y herencia para crear un Componente.

Ahora para dejar en claro esto, tanto esta función

```
function User(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}
```

y este fragmento de código

```
User: function(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}
```

no son equivalentes ni la una remplaza a la otra hablando estrictamente respecto a ES6 y ES5, pero hablando de React estas tienen una cercanía.

Aqui un ejemplo de creación de componente de React en ES5

```
const MiModal = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>Mi Modal.</div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Como mencioné en ES5 no existen clases ni herencia por lo tanto varias librerías proveen su propio mecanismo para emularlas, todas estas librerias implementan el mecanismo *factory pattern* para emular herencia.

En el caso de React este mecanismo (*factory pattern*) es expuesto por la función createClass, esta recibe un objeto donde tu "sobre escribes" y defines tus propios metodos, pero lo que envías es un objeto (clave -> valor), por lo tanto este fragmento de código que escribes.

```
User: function(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}
```

es un fragmento de la definición de un objeto.

```
{
  User: function(props) {
      return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
  }
}
```

objeto que en React se usa como parametro del metodo fabrica .createClass para que este fabrique el componente.

```
const MiModal = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>Mi Modal.</div>
      );
    },

    User: function(props) {
      return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
    }
  }
);
```

Si quieres llamar a este "método" del componente MiModal debes hacerlo de esta manera, dentro del componente (puedes llamar la función fuera del componente pero no le veo sentido.)

```
const MiModal = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Cuenta.</h1>
          <ul>
            {this.User(this.props)}
            <li>Cerrar Sesión.</>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    },

    User: function(props) {
      return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
    }
  }
);
```

Si quieres hacerlo en ES6 pues la cosa es mucho mas fácil, aquí el lenguaje soporta clases y herencia por lo tanto todo se simplifica sintácticamente y es mas natural.

```
class MiModal extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Cuenta.</h1>
          <ul>
            {this.User(this.props)}
            <li>Cerrar Sesión.</>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  User = (props) => {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
  }
}
```

Luego de la explicación puedo señalar las confusiones que puedo notar en tu pregunta.

1- En tu primer fragmento de código

```
function User(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}
```

Puedes usarla en un componente de esta manera.

```
function User(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}

const MiModal = React.createClass(
  {
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Cuenta.</h1>
          <ul>
            <User {...this.props} />
            <li>Cerrar Sesión.</>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

tampoco corresponde a la definición de un método de una clase en ES6 pero igual lo puedes usar.

```
function User(props) {
    return (<li>{props.userName}</li>);
}

class MiModal extends React.Component {
  ...
  render(){
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>Cuenta.</h1>
          <ul>
            <User {...this.props} />
            <li>Cerrar Sesión.</>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por responder! Si bien me aclaraste varias dudas, leyendo artículos como estos: https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/ y http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-react-createclass-es6-classes-or-stateless-functional-components/ Me di cuenta que puedo hacer una función y montarlo, es mas, mejora la performance cuando no se necesita llamar a 'this' dentro del componente. Ya comencé a utilizar la notación <User /> y por el momento queda joya. Saludos!

Comment: @Genarito gracias por tu respuesta no había leído esa parte de componentes funcionales en React, aprendi algo nuevo :D, corregí mi respuesta si no te sirve me avisas para eliminarla

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido el comentario! Ahí la marqué como correcta! Gracias nuevamente por responder

Answer (score 1):

En ES6 existe una caracteristica llamada `Method Properties` que permite definir los metodos de un objeto como:

```
obj = {
    foo (a, b) {
        …
    },
    bar (x, y) {
        …
    },
    *quux (x, y) {
        …
    }
}
```

Con el equivalente en ES6:

```
obj = {
    foo: function (a, b) {
        …
    },
    bar: function (x, y) {
        …
    },
    //  quux: no equivalent in ES5
    …
};
```

Toma en cuenta que esto solo es valido cuando enumeras las propiedades de un objeto.

Ahora, sobre la notacion JSX que es la que nos permite expandir un componente como si fuera HTML, considera que el equivalente a

```
<User user={props.user} />
```

Es:

```
React.createElement(User, { user: props.user });
```

Recuerda que JSX no es JS y require ser compilado. Puedes probar el compilador en linea [aqui](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&code=function%20hello()%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20%3Cdiv%3EHello%20world!%3C%2Fdiv%3E%3B%0A%7D).